# Why does autoboxing fail for ArrayList.remove(char)? It treats char as int

Tags: java, java-8

I was really puzzled at why ArrayList.remove() gives a stack overflow :D

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 98 out of bounds for length 3
```

**But this is not 'C'. char is semantically closer to Character than it is to int.**

my code (minimum number of steps to convert strings s to t):

```
public class Solution {

    public int minSteps(String s, String t) {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : t.toCharArray()) {
            list.add(c);
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println("trying to remove " + c);
            list.remove(c);
            System.out.println(" result: " + list);
        }
        return list.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        String s = "bab";
        String t = "aba";
        System.out.println("minSteps: s " + sol.minSteps(s, t));
    }

    public Solution() {
    }
}
```

the console output is

```
[a, b, a]
trying to remove b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 98 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:502)
    at com.sandbox.Solution.minSteps(Solution.java:25)
    at com.sandbox.Solution.main(Solution.java:35)
```

The strange thing is when I try to do

```
boolean b = list.remove(c);
```

It will not compile!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.Character cannot be converted to boolean
    at com.sandbox.Solution.minSteps(Solution.java:25)
    at com.sandbox.Solution.main(Solution.java:35)
```

When I explicitly convert c to Character, it works.
This tells me that [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is not working here!

```
    boolean b = list.remove(Character.valueOf(c));

[a, b, a]
trying to remove b
 result: [a, a]
trying to remove a
 result: [a]
trying to remove b
 result: [a]
minSteps: s 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has 2 `remove` methods:

- [`E remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)
- [`boolean remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

`remove(c)` can call either of them, either by widening the `char` value to an `int`, or auto-boxing the `char` value to a `Character`.

For backwards compatibility reasons, the compiler will always prefer a simple widening over auto-boxing, so the compiler chooses to make the call `remove((int) c)`.

To force it to call the other method, do one of the following:

- Box the `char` yourself:

  ```
  remove(Character.valueOf(c))
  ```
- Force auto-boxing with a cast:

  ```
  remove((Character) c)
  ```

If you don't like the extra stuff in the `remove` call, you could alternatively do one of the following:

- Trigger auto-boxing in the loop:

  ```
  for (Character c : s.toCharArray())
  ```
- Trigger auto-boxing in a separate statement:

  ```
  Character cBoxed = c;
  list.remove(cBoxed);
  ```

Comment: `For backwards compatibility reasons, the compiler will always prefer a simple widening over auto-boxing` not in the documentation for the method.

Comment: @likejudo That is documented in the *Java Language Specification*, section [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2): Phase 1: Attempt to find method without using auto-boxing. Phase 2: If no method found yet, attempt to find method using of auto-boxing. --- Choose between overloads is a global Java thing, not specific to these 2 methods, so of course it's not documented for the method.

Comment: But this is not 'C'. It should have tried `char` as `Character` before trying it as `int`.

Comment: But this is not 'C'. char is semantically closer to Character than it is to int.

Comment: @likejudo Not according to the **rules of determining the method signature** as defined by the **Java Language Specification**, and I already gave to the link to that. The rules are whatever the *language designers* decided they are, and they decided that *widening* wins over *auto-boxing*, for **backwards compatibility reasons,** as already stated in the answer.

Comment: @likejudo I also said that in a previous comment, that somehow got deleted. --- And I'm not sure what *"this is not 'C'"* has to do with anything, but you are correct: This is **Java**, not C, and we all know that, because you tagged `java` in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```java
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
```

You are working with the primitive type `char` here so `c` is not an object. When you call `list.remove(c);` not the method `remove(Object)` is used but `remove(int)` because the character is implicitly converted to its integer equivalent from unicode.

Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) for documentation of the methods.

Comment: But this is not 'C'. char is semantically closer to Character than it is to int.

Comment: @likejudo ```char``` **is** a number, keep that in mind. It is a *primitive* datatype. Imagine two functions ```f(long)``` and ```f(Object)```. Now if I pass some integer to ```f``` by your logic it would be "converted" to ```Integer``` and then given to ```f(Object)```. This would be obviously strange.